# Appending Rows to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am stuck on a simple task. I want to create an empty DataFrame and append rows to it based on a query of another dataset. I have tried the answers here but  I am missing something ..beginner Pythoner. Any help would be appreciated. I want to take the top 3 rows of each state and add them into a new dataframe for processing. I tried to append also..

```py
def test():

    #get the list of states
    states_df = census_df.STNAME.unique()
    population_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for st in states_df:
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(census_df[census_df['STNAME'] == st].nlargest(3,'CENSUS2010POP'))
        pd.concat([temp_df, population_df], ignore_index = True)

    return 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what course you're doing, I had a great time with that a year ago, keep it up!

The simplest/fastest way I've found to concatenate a bunch of sliced dataframes is to append each df to a list, then at the end just concatenate that list. See the working code below (it does what I interpret you meant).

I agree with David's suggestion on sorting, easier to use sort and then just slice the first 3. As nlargest() works on and returns a Series I believe and not a dataframe, whereas you want to keep the whole dataframe structure (all the columns) for concatenation.

Also why is your function returning 1? Typo? I guess you want to return your desired output if you're putting it in a function, so I changed that too.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#create fake data random numbers
data = np.random.randint(2,11,(40,3))
census_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(40), columns=['Blah', 'Blah2','CENSUS2010POP'], data=data)
#create fake STNAME column
census_df['STNAME'] = list('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffgggghhhhiiiijjjj')

#Function:
def test(census_df):
    states_list = census_df.STNAME.unique() #changed naming to _list as it's not a df.
    list_of_dfs = list() #more efficient to append each df to a list
    for st in states_list:
        temp_df = census_df[census_df['STNAME']==st]
        temp_df = temp_df.sort_values(by=['CENSUS2010POP'], ascending=False).iloc[:3]
        list_of_dfs.append(temp_df)
    population_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs,ignore_index=True)
    return population_df

population_df = test(census_df)
```

Comment: @mynameisarjay of course! It's course 1 of a 5 course specialization on Coursera: [https://www.coursera.org/specializations/data-science-python](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/data-science-python). For a beginner such as I was it's very tough and demanding, but equally rewarding. I only did the first 3 courses, but even by the end of that, I was already achieving some supervised machine learning activities.

Comment: @Declan - Thanks a bunch. Yes, I am working my way through course 1 of the specialization! No doubt you will see me here more often. The return 1 was only so that it doesn't get in my way, I was debugging using print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! Is your problem appending or the top three rows?

For append, try the [df.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) function. It could look something like:

```
#get the list of states
states_df = census_df.STNAME.unique()
population_df = pd.DataFrame()

for st in states_df:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(census_df[census_df['STNAME'] == st].nlargest(3,'CENSUS2010POP'))
    population_df = population_df.append(temp_df, ignore_index = True) #append the temp df to your main df, ignoring the index
```

For the top rows you could us df.sort_values(by=['column name'],ascending=False) and then select the top three rows:

```
population_df = population_df.append(temp_df[0:3], ignore_index = True)
```